# overridePendingTransition when launching an Intent via Preferences

Tags: android

Is there a way to `overridePendingTransition` when launching an `Intent` via `PreferenceActivity`?

```
<Preference
        android:title="Settings">
    <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="dot.com.app"
            android:targetClass="dot.com.app.activities.SettingsActivity" />
</Preference>
```

Programmatically, it can be done by:

```
SettingsActivity.this.finish();
overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the onCreate(), onBackPressed()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your PreferenceActivity, obviously pick your own animations.

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    super.startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but startActivity still showed the animation when set to 0, 0.